# Can't build iOS app with own Static Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I created Cocoa Touch Static Library, that uses some CocoaPods.
Now I'm creating an app, that uses that library. And when I try to build app, Xcode says:

```
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: can't locate file for: -lPods
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: file: -lPods is not an object file (not allowed in a library)
```

Can any one help, what should I do to resolve this errors? Thanks!